# How does struts2 run its validate method?

Tags: java, ajax, validation, struts2, xml-validation

I am doing an XML form validation and form validation with `validate()` method. The XML validation is to check if they filled out the required fields, are the fields in proper length and etc. while the validate method performs database look up if the entered value exist in the database. if it does exist it will add a field error.

Now my problem. when I submit the form and I did not fill out the `requiredstrings`  it will add an error to page, but when I enter a valid value it still prompts the same error(and at the same time it does not call the validate method).

this is my form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
<head>

<sj:head/>  
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Register for a prize by completing this form.</h3>
    <div id="divErrors">
    </div>

    <s:form action="register" id ="result">
            <label>UserName</label>
            <s:textfield name="userBean.username" />
            <s:fielderror/>
        <sj:submit 
                    targets="result" 
                    value="AJAX Submit" 
                    indicator="indicator"
                    button="true"
                    />

    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Register-validation.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="userBean.username">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>User name is required.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

And my `validate` from the `RegisterAction` class.

```
public void validate(){

        if(userBean != null && userBean.getUsername().equals("foo")){
            this.addFieldError("userBean.username", "That Username already exist");

        }

    }
```

The Scenario what I am doing.

I will submit the form without filling up the required string, and then I will enter a valid value, after the submitting the form the same error still exist.

Comment: So you are saying that xml validation is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that the validation framework in Struts2 by default returns the `input` result if the validation fails. If the `input` is the JSP page that is the form inside, then as you make ajax call  then the whole page will be replaced.

Second time you've made the *valid* call, so after the validation the `execute` method should return the result. And this result should be the JSP fragment that replaced on the page at the target `"result"`, that is the form element. But the div `"divErrors"` is not replaced by your code. If it had errors rendered on the first request, then it will be there.

Ok, I think it worth enough to make understanding ajax and validation. And you understand now how to solve the problem that returns result that is not expected.

Comment: Thanks Roman C, I've realized that way after I asked this question. but thank you for your input anyway. this was on December 20 last year. Haha

Comment: I was not able to answer that time :(, if you like it you may accept it too :) the answer before me looks weird :)

Comment: @pathfinder2104 If you have a question you should post it via [Ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -1):

A lot of things could be happening. "userbean" may not be initializing, for example.

You are also using two validations: the one in the XML, which should be working if you have configured the Validator interceptor (see http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/interceptors.html ), and the validate() method.

- Check if you have getters and setters for userbean
- Breakpoint at the validate() method to inspect the contents of userbean there

Comment: I have setters and getters for userBean, apparently userBean is being initialized. it is returning a value.

Comment: So what happens in the validate() breakpoint? Do you get inside the if clause?

Comment: Also, why do you have both XML validation and an identical rule in validate() ?